# Identifying records with double space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in generating a script to identify records under the 'Postcode' column that has double space in between instead of single space.

Table name: Tabu2

```
Cit_ID   DOB    Status Postcode
1        12/84   S     KT1  3GP
2        11/81   S     KT2 2PI
3        13/80   M     KT1  2PP
4        15/78   M     KT3  2ON
5        13/67   M     KT5 4II
```

Many thanks

Comment: `WHERE Postcode LIKE '%  %'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select *
 From Tabu2
 Where Postcode like '%  %'
```

Or

```
Select *
 From Tabu2
 Where CharIndex('  ',Postcode)>0
```

To fix

```
Update Tabu2 set Postcode=Replace(Postcode,'  ',' ')
 Where  CharIndex('  ',Postcode)>0
```

Comment: @optimisteve Data Hygiene is a consent battle

Comment: What does the >0 represent in the script?

Comment: @optimisteve >0 indicates that the string was found.  Charindex() returns the position

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where postcode like '%  %'
```